# Numpy , Python3.6 - not able to understand why address is different?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

Here is my Code

```
my_array_1 = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
print(my_array_1)

my_array_red = my_array_1[:, 1::2]
print(my_array_red)

my_array_blue = my_array_1[1::2, 0:3:2]
print(my_array_blue)

my_array_yellow = my_array_1[-1, :]
print(my_array_yellow)

print(id(my_array_1))
print(id(my_array_red))
print(id(my_array_yellow))
print(id(my_array_blue))

print(my_array_1.data)
print(my_array_red.data)
print(my_array_blue.data)
print(my_array_yellow.data)
```

Here is the Output:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24]]
[[ 1  3]
 [ 6  8]
 [11 13]
 [16 18]
 [21 23]]
[[ 5  7]
 [15 17]]
[20 21 22 23 24]
2606769150592
2606769282544
2607017647120
2606769282624
<memory at 0x0000025EFE56CA68>
<memory at 0x0000025EFE56CA68>
<memory at 0x0000025EFE56CA68>
<memory at 0x0000025EFE5A8F48>
```

Question :
Just check the last 4 lines of my output . why my_array_1.data.data , my_array_red.data, my_array_blue.data have same value , But where as my_array_yellow.data have a different value ?

Answer (score 2):

I find the `data` value of the `__array_interface__` to be more informative:

```
In [2]: my_array_1.__array_interface__['data']
Out[2]: (33691856, False)
In [3]: my_array_red.__array_interface__['data']
Out[3]: (33691864, False)
In [4]: my_array_blue.__array_interface__['data']
Out[4]: (33691896, False)
In [5]: my_array_yellow.__array_interface__['data']
Out[5]: (33692016, False)
```

`Out[2]` is the start of the data buffer.

`red` is 8 bytes larger - that is one element from the start.

`blue` is 40 bytes in - the next row

```
In [8]: my_array_1.strides
Out[8]: (40, 8)
```

`yellow` is 160 bytes in - that's the start of the last row (40 from the end)

```
In [9]: 2016-1856
Out[9]: 160
In [10]: my_array_1.nbytes
Out[10]: 200
```

---

The `data` addresses all differ, but are in the same ballpark.  But they are harder to interpret.

```
In [11]: my_array_1.data
Out[11]: <memory at 0x7fa975369a68>
In [12]: my_array_red.data
Out[12]: <memory at 0x7fa975369b40>
In [13]: my_array_blue.data
Out[13]: <memory at 0x7fa975369c18>
In [14]: my_array_yellow.data
Out[14]: <memory at 0x7fa9710f11c8>
```

---

The `data` attribute can be used in an `ndarray` constructor:

Two elements from `yellow`:

```
In [17]: np.ndarray(2,dtype=my_array_1.dtype,buffer=my_array_yellow.data)
Out[17]: array([20, 21])
```

Same 2 elements, but with the original address, and an offset (as deduced above):

```
In [18]: np.ndarray(2,dtype=my_array_1.dtype,buffer=my_array_1.data, offset=160)
Out[18]: array([20, 21])
```

---

Actually the `data` display doesn't tell us anything about where the data buffer is located.  It's the address of the `memoryview` object that references the buffer, not the address of the buffer itself.  Call `data` again, and get a different memoryview object:

```
In [19]: my_array_1.data
Out[19]: <memory at 0x7fa975369cf0>
```

---

If I print these memoryview objects, I get the same pattern as you do:

```
In [22]: print(my_array_1.data)
<memory at 0x7fa970e37120>
In [23]: print(my_array_red.data)
<memory at 0x7fa970e37120>
In [24]: print(my_array_blue.data)
<memory at 0x7fa970e37120>
In [25]: print(my_array_yellow.data)
<memory at 0x7fa9710f17c8>
```

For 23 and 24, it's just reusing a memory slot, because with print there's no persistence.  I'm not sure why `yellow` doesn't reuse it, except maybe the object is sufficiently different that it doesn't fit in the same space. In the `Out[11]` etc. cases, the `ipython` buffering hangs onto those objects, and thus there's not reuse.

It just reinforces the idea that there's nothing significant about the print display of these `memoryview objects`.  It has nothing to do with the databuffer location.  It's more like the `id`, just an arbitrary place in memory.

Comment: It doesn't appear that your data attributes show the same behavior as OP's. It's probably due to the late hour, but I fail to see how this addresses OP's exact question. Still learned something new though.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I just realized, or remembered, that `.data` is a `memoryview object which references the given object`.  It doesn't show the address of the databuffer.

Comment: That explains a lot more. The addresses are just identical by coincidence. Thanks.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, the coincidence is because with `print` there's no persistence, the addresses can be reused..

Comment: I understood that part. I just didn't know that data was a memoryview any more than op, apparently.